# Does IDataReader.GetName(i) work with empty data readers?

Tags: c#, idatareader

I want in the case of an empty data reader to output the field names with empty values.. ie

Product: -
Price: -

So, are IDataReader.GetName(i) and IDataReader.FieldCount safe to use when they have no results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually i just tested this my self, executing a reader against an empty set. Then without calling Read(); i successfully red the FieldCount, and GetName(i) for all columns while the data reader had 0 rows.